# Jquery - improve Quiz/Test code

Tags: jquery

I'm 'demoing' a shop that only allows the user to buy the product if they provide a passphrase given by shop's admin or if they pass a "test/quiz". The test "happens" in a WhatsApp-like interface.

Most of the work I do with jquery is toggle classes so when I try to do something with a bit of logic I end up with looong and ugly code.

Let's the code (commented) speak by itself :
http://jsfiddle.net/polmoneys/Eje2s/9/

*This works but If I want to extend the amount of questions this approach starts looking like a terrible way to go. How can this code be improved?*

I was wondering if I should change the markup entirely and use a "position" approach (some sort of for loop with `nth-child(i)` glamourous thing which goes beyond my current knowledge) and play with `.next()`, `.is(:visible)` and such.

*thanks*

EDIT: 
after some try and error I can reduce some of the specific code and make it more generic 
(erased fiddle as I can only place two links per post)

**Final Edit**

After trying with Flater's advice I came up with this:
(erased fiddle as I can only place two links per post)

Only problem now seems to be how to accept both inputs from user as valid passphrase reardless if first letter is uppercase* (thinking on iOS here) and how to apply a timer/Countdown to the quiz. I've placed some code on fiddle, can't make it work

**Mega Final Edit**
all issues solved :)
http://jsfiddle.net/polmoneys/ZL5xx/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two tips:

1st. Make use of arrays:

```
var pass_phrase_list = new Array();
pass_phrase_list["1"] = "boogedyboo";
pass_phrase_list["2"] = "flobbadobbadob";
...
```

2nd. Use classes instead of IDs. Use the IDs for identifying the index of an array.

```
<input type="button" class="check_click" id="button_1" />
<input type="text" class="check_me" id="checkfield_1" />

$('.check_click').click(function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("button_",""); //gets the id of the button

    var value = $("#checkfield_"+id).val();            //Gets the value of the input with the same ID.

    if (value == pass_phrase_list[id]) {               //Checks the input value against the item in the array that has the same index.
        ...
    }

    ...
});
```

Of course, I would suggest another way to populate the passphrases-array, since users can see the javascript code in the source. But I hope you understand what I mean :)

**Update**
You can use a similar approach for all underlying code regarding the loading of new questions etc...

Answer (score 0):

[Coffeescript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) might help you with this. You can at least make the code more readable and it makes working with jquery easier.  Any possibility of using it?

Comment: I'm afraid I need babysteps, js basis first :)